# Trouble with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, backend, docker-registry

```
lafs-api  | > learn-angular-from-scratch-step-by-step-api@1.0.0 start /usr/src/lafs
lafs-api  | > node .
lafs-api  |
lafs-api  | /usr/src/lafs/node_modules/@swagger-api/apidom-core/cjs/serializers/value/ast/ephemeral-array.cjs:6
lafs-api  |   type = 'EphemeralArray';
lafs-api  |        ^
lafs-api  |
lafs-api  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
lafs-api  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
lafs-api  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
lafs-api  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
lafs-api  |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
lafs-api  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
lafs-api  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
lafs-api  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
lafs-api  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/lafs/node_modules/@swagger-api/apidom-core/cjs/serializers/value/index.cjs:8:46)
```

I'm getting this error when i try to run docker-compose up command in powershell from the lafs-api directory. I will create the two docker containers together but the lafs-api container doesn't work correctly and just constantly starts and restarts.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
# REST API running on Node JS container
 app:
   container_name: lafs-api
   restart: always
   build: .
   ports:
    - '3000:3000'
  # link this container to the Mongo DB container
   links:
    - mongo
  # pass in environment variables for database host and name
   environment:
    - DB_HOST=mongo
    - DB_NAME=lafs-db
# Mongo DB storage container
 mongo:
   container_name: lafs-db
   image: 'mongo:4'
   ports:
   - '27017:27017'
# Attach the external network to these containers
networks:
  default:
   external:
    name: lafs-net
```

I've tried updating my node and deleting my node_module folder and rerunning npm install but it hasn't helped. When I asked chat gpt it said that this usually happens when the version of node is not compatable but I'm unsure where to go from here. This is a class project and they want us to be using 10.23.0. Any help would be appricated.

Comment: This doesn't look like a docker problem, but a problem with the node application you're trying to start.

Comment: Yes, I just don't know what to do or where to go from here.

Comment: Try using another container.

Comment: (This isn't your problem, but the `links:` option is obsolete and you can safely just delete that block.  You can simplify things even further by deleting the `container_name:` options and the `networks:` block at the end; Compose will generate names for all of these things, and you don't usually need to know them.  You would need to change `DB_NAME=mongo` to match the Compose service name of the database.)